# In Firebase Analytics, how to filter data by specific app

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have multiple apps in one firebase project.
Can I show data analytics by a specific app?

Answer (score 8):

I found it in Google Analytics page.
It is stream name Dimension

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: When viewing any report in Firebase Analytics, you can: Add comparison > Dimension = "Stream name" > Match Type = "exactly matches" > Value: select your app via checkbox eg. "com.organization.appname" (this allows you to only check eg. your production app and exclude your dev/staging apps)